# ASP.NET Photo API (Shutterfly, etc . .)

Tags: c#, asp.net, photos

I have a website with all my photos, I would like people to be able to click on my pictures and order prints, etc through a third party service (Shutterfly, etc).  Does anyone have any best practices or code examples of doing this in C#, ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this information is still up to date, but here is a [description of the Shutterfly API](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~ben/c4p_API_v2.html). The API seems to consist in a simple **HTTP form post with embedded name-value pairs**.

Example:

```
<form action="http://www.shutterfly.com/c4p/UpdateCart.jsp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="addim" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="protocol" value="SFP,100">
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="C4P">
<input type="hidden" name="puid" value="AFFL">
<input type="hidden" name="imnum" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="imraw-1" value="http://images.partner.com/foo/12345.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="imrawheight-1" value="1800">
<input type="hidden" name="imrawwidth-1" value="1200">
<input type="hidden" name="imthumb-1" value="http://images.partner.com/foo/12345_thumb.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="imthumbheight-1" value="150">
<input type="hidden" name="imthumbwidth-1" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="returl" value="http://www.partner.com/alice">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It should not be a difficult task to write some C# wrapper for it.

Comment: Seems more complicated now with OAuth, XML, etc.: http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/start.sfly